# AnyLogic - Move presentation frame dynamicaly

Tags: modeling, anylogic

I've got a model with cars moving over the road. To make roads length similar to real-life sizes I had to change the scale so the cars turned into points (4px*2px).

Are there any facilities in AnyLogic 7 PLE to, for ex, zoom one of the cars and track it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. If you want to zoom in one car and follow it in 3D (like if the car has GoPro at top), use `Camera` object with dynamic coordinates. Railway Station example model and its `cameraOnTrain` object illustrates the concept.

In case if you want to do similar thing in 2D space (GTA2 view mode), you may drag & drop empty `Group` element. In its `On Draw` action use the code:
`getPresentation().getPanel().setOffsets( 300-agent.getX(), 300-agent.getY());`

The code will constantly move frame, so car always will appear with in the bottom right corner of the 300x300 square, drawn from top left corner. Zoom can be adjusted with mouse wheel, or with code as well: 
`getPresentation().getPanel().setZoom( double value);`

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I need.